# "driver cannot be resolved" in my Java program

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, helper

I am very new to programming. My main goal is to write code that logs into a **android** app and does everything that you would have to do with your fingers. So far I've only got the app to open, now I'm stuck on entering the login information.

I am not familiar with every aspect that has to do with Java, Eclipse, Appium, and Selenium.

Here is my code:

```
package OpenOfferUpTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OpenOfferUp {


@Test
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
File OfferUp = new File("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\OfferUp.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.offerup.android.login.splash.LoginSplashActivity");

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}
@Test
public void SimpleTest() {

    driver.findElement(By.id("email_button")).sendKeys("sourgta@gmail.com");

}



}
```

At *driver*, it is underlined red, and says that it cannot be resolved. I am not sure on how to fix this.

These are the options I am given:

[image: I am not allowed to add pictures yet, so please bare with me.]

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: I have trimmed quite a lot of chatty material from this. Readers here often appreciate an indication that a question author is new to a particular area, though this is usually evident from the question itself. However, that does not mean they are keen to fix every little thing for you - any help at all on a volunteer site is good, so it is usually better not to add various extra demands about what would constitute a helpful answer.

Comment: From a learning perspective, if you only get a hint at a solution, that can be useful in giving you a new avenue of research. While I agree there are probably some things that are reasonably out of the grasp of beginners, we also do not want to encourage beginners into a "helplessness mindset", where they insist they are not capable, and thus will not try. [This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) about confident questions may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
package OpenOfferUpTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OpenOfferUp {

AndroidDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
File OfferUp = new File("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\OfferUp.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.offerup.android.login.splash.LoginSplashActivity");

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}
@Test
public void SimpleTest() {

    driver.findElement(By.id("email_button")).sendKeys("sourgta@gmail.com");

}

}
```

Try updated code

Comment: @Before
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException. **The "@Before" is now underlined red, any help?**

Comment: Also, in console it reads - **[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
FAILED: SimpleTest
java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Try updated code

Comment: This shows up in console. **[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
Feb 20, 2019 10:02:18 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest OpensOfferUp**